# SharePoint 2010 - Add new item to custom list error

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a List in SP 2010 on the root site, and i want to re-use this List in other sites and places, so as usual i did save a template from this list , and create a new one using the saved template, so far so good, then when i tried to add new item into the new list nothing happens , the list won't save the items and no errors occurs, just an empty list.

Any Ideas ..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , i figured out the case, it is like this , when you create a list from a saved as template list it takes all configurations and settings, in my case the issue was that in the original list settings the versioning was enabled and the approval settings as well , so when i changed the settings to its original status and then added items successfully, then i can go back to list settings and configure it again to keep previous versions, and yes to the need approval setting as well.